# Installed Linux Mint - HDMI and general Nvidia graphics issues

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon

I installed Linux for the first time using Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Nvidia has been giving me grief and the applet just disappeared for some reason.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia*
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                        all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-430                       430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64                430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:i386                 430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:amd64                 430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:i386                  430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:amd64                 430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:i386                  430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386                    430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:amd64                     430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:i386                      430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386                    430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                        amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-430                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                        amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-430                            430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-430                          430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                        amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-430                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-430                   430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                         all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-prime-applet                        1.0.7                                           all          An applet for NVIDIA Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-430                           430.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                         amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
```

I'm confused as to why these things have happened!

Comment: Please, describe better the issue and attach log (`journalctl`) in order to show warnings/errors